# Changing the font size of an NSButton doesn't change anything

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, nsbutton

I'm working on my first Swift project (hooray), which is an app for Mac OS. What I want to do now is create some buttons, with a white text color and a custom font. Because I needed a new attribute on that button to hold some data, I made a child class of `NSButton`.

Now, I know that I can set the font of a button like this:

```
super.font = NSFont(name: "NB-International-Pro", size: 40)
```

Which worked like a charm. After that I tried to change the color of the text by doing this:

```
let pstyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
pstyle.alignment = .center
super.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: (device?.name)!, attributes: [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : NSColor.white, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : pstyle ])
```

Which did work, and it did change the color of the text, however, now the font and font size are back to default. Is there an option to do both?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't really have to subclass NSButton to accomplish this. It can be easily done in your XIB file. In the Interface Builder property inspector, select your button and set the Type to Momentary Change and then enter buttonicon under Image and buttonicon2 under Alternate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the font first, include the font name and size in your attributes when creating your `NSAttributedString` by using the `NSFontAttributeName` and `NSFontSizeAttribute` keys:

```
attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: (device?.name)!, attributes: [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : NSColor.white, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : pstyle, NSFontAttributeName: "NB-International-Pro", NSFontSizeAttribute: 40])
```

Beyond that there's probably some improvements you can make to the architecture of your code. Subclassing `NSButton` is not really needed just for changing text style (can be done either in .xib or your view controller).